# Fixed positioned <div>

Tags: html, position, css-position, fixed

I have 3 div elements in this format:

```
<div class='primary'>
    Some paragraphs.
    <div class="fixed"> Fixed div element.</div>
    <div class="scrolling"> Scrollable paragraph </div>
</div primary>
```

After some paragraphs in the primary `<div>`, there's a fixed `<div>` element. After the fixed `<div>`, there'll be scrollable paragraph. What I'd like to do is to fix the "primary" & "fixed" `<div>` elements to be fixed while the "scrolling" `<div>` will be scrollable inside the primary `<div>`.

When I scroll, only the content in the "scrolling" div element(the last div) should move while the rest(the first two) stays the same. How do I achieve this?

I've been playing around with the `position: fixed;` and `position: relative;` but I couldn't find what I wanted.
Here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrqbn410/) outline.

Comment: What are the heights of your div/s?

Comment: The primary div's height is the height of the browser's window. So, it's 100%. The height of the fixed div is 100px. For the last scrolling div is what's left from the primary div.

Comment: Are you using **jQuery** library?

Comment: Yup. I'm using jQuery.

Comment: Ok. Then I suggest you use jquery to do it. If you want I will post my answer using **jQuery**.

Comment: That'll be really helpful. I'm fairly new to html :)

Comment: yeah. it's fixed. the only thing that's not fixed is the scrollable div element

Comment: I posted my answer using css and jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Why try that way by giving specific height to your `Scrolling` div and make some changes in your CSS. check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrqbn410/2/) please.

I've just made changes in your `scrolling` div as follow.

```
.scrolling{
    border: 3px solid black;
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: scroll;
    width:100%;
}
```

**Update:**

Or you can remove scroll bar from bottom by little changes in your parent and scrolling class in CSS. Check new [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hrqbn410/8/)

```
.primary{
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.scrolling{
    border: 3px solid black;
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Please Note the `Overflow: hidden` on Parent div and and `Overflow: auto` on scrolling one.

Answer (score 1):

Using **css** and **jQuery**:

You need to wrap the **first paragraph** and `fixed` class with `div`.

**E.g.** `<div class="fixed-div">`

```
<div class="primary">
    <div class="fixed-div">
        Some paragraphs.
        <br />
        Some paragraphs.
        <br />
        Some paragraphs. 
        Some paragraphs.
        Some paragraphs.
        Some paragraphs.
        <div class="fixed">
            Fixed div element.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrolling">
        xxx Scrollable paragraphs.Scrollable paragraphs.Scrollable paragraphs.Scrollable
    </div>
</div>
```

**Then,** you need to add css properties to `fixed-div`, `fixed`, and `scrolling` classes.

```
.fixed-div {
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.fixed {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
}

.scrolling {
    border: 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Last,** jquery codes: You need to use **jquery** to detect the height of the `fixed-div` class then assign the top property of `scrolling` class by the height of `fixed-div` class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var fixedDivHeight = $('.fixed-div').height();
    $('.scrolling').css('top', fixedDivHeight);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        fixedDivHeight = $('.fixed-div').height();
        $('.scrolling').css('top', fixedDivHeight);
    });

});
```

**Here's the [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/hrqbn410/11/).**

Hope it helps.